# Alpha-beta in Connect Four

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

My minimax algorithm is returning very bad move choice after I apply alpha-beta pruning to the game of Connect Four.

```
def get_next_move(board, player, depth, alpha, beta) :
    score = get_score(board, depth)
    if score is not None :
        return score, board
    if depth == 0 :
        return 0, board

    if player is AI :
        best = LOSS
        best_move = None
        possible_moves = get_possible_moves(board, player)

        for move in possible_moves :
            move_score = get_next_move(move, PLAYER, depth-1, alpha, beta)[0]
            if move_score >= best :
                best = move_score
                best_move = move
                alpha = max(alpha, best)
            if alpha >= beta :
                break
        return best, best_move
    else :
        best = WIN
        best_move = None
        possible_moves = get_possible_moves(board, player)

        for move in possible_moves :
            move_score = get_next_move(move, AI, depth-1, alpha, beta)[0]
            if move_score <= best :
                best = move_score
                best_move = move
                beta = min(best, beta)

            if beta <= alpha :
                break
        return best, best_move
```

Everything works fine until I try to implement alpha-beta.

Comment: You'll need to show us the `get_score` and `get_possible_moves` functions. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your implementation of the alpha-beta algorithm, so your heuristics might be the problem.